# Loading ResourceManager from separate assembly produces FileNotFound?

Tags: c#, reflection, filenotfoundexception, resourcemanager

I have an assembly I'm trying to load with reflection and read a Resource string from.

So, I use something like this:

```
        config.Extras="C:\dev\foo.dll";
        string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string tmp = Path.GetDirectoryName(config.Extras[0]);
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(tmp);
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(config.Extras[0]);
        foreach (var item in asm.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(item, asm);
                string foo=rm.GetString("foo"); //error here
        }
```

However, this throws a FileNotFoundException because it can't find a referenced assembly of `foo.dll`. Foo.dll has a dependency on `Bar.dll`. It throws the error saying it can't find `bar.dll`. The actual location of `bar.dll` though is in the same directory as `foo.dll`.

So, how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Never use LoadFile(), the loaded assembly has no load context.  Use LoadFrom().

Comment: @HansPassant that fixed it. If you make than an answer, I'll accept it. heh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Load methods in the Assembly class suffer from a naming problem.  Nobody ever gets Load() wrong.  But LoadFile() has a *much* too attractive name.  LoadFrom should have been LoadFile and LoadFile should have been LoadButUseThisOnlyWhenYouReallyKnowWhatItDoes().

The loading context for an assembly is difficult to understand.  Suzanne Cooke has blogged about it a lot, not otherwise putting much of a dent into explaining it :)  Roughly, when you use LoadFile, the CLR does not keep track of where the assembly came from and won't stop you from loading the assembly more than once.  The types in that assembly are unique and the same type loaded from two LoadFile calls are not identical.  You only ever use LoadFile when you *intentionally* don't want a match.  The kind of thing that programs that read metadata would be interested in, a decompiler for example.

The "does not keep track of where the assembly came from" clause is the problem here.  You need to use LoadFrom().